# Prevent Git checkout from copying directories from other branch

Tags: git

Example:

branch-one

```
| assets # directories
| views
| core
```

branch-two

```
index.html # only one source file
```

When switching between these two branches (i.e. on branch-one to branch-two), all of the directories from branch-one are being copied over.

Example:

```
> # on branch-one
> mkdir assets views core
> git add .

> git status
  On branch branch-one

  No commits yet

  nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)

> git commit -m "directories"
  On branch branch-one

  Initial commit

  nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)

> git checkout -b branch-two
  Switched to a new branch 'branch-two'

> git status
  On branch branch-two

  No commits yet

  nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)

> ls
  assets/ core/ views/
```

Now in my branch-two, all of the directories are copied over (which I don't want).

Question:

How do I move between branches without the source files (or directories) between them being copied over?

Comment: Ok.. I think we need the whole thing. Right before committing, run `git status`. Right _after_ committing, do the same. Right after checking out branch-two, do the same. Paste all the commands and their outputs in the question.... please.

Comment: This happens because empty directories are not tracked by Git and has nothing to do with the *.gitignore* rules. Please be **very careful** when using suggestions found in other answers on Stack Overflow or websites that propose to use *git clean* as this command affects all untracked files.

Comment: FYI you can commit "empty directories" by creating a file named `.gitkeep` in these folders if needed (though it's not really empty directories anymore then). In this case the directories would not appear when switching to `branch-two`.

Answer (score 3):

As in [this SuperUser answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1472515/does-git-delete-empty-folders) by slhck:

> Git does not track directories; it only tracks files.
>
> If there are no files in a directory, that directory does not “exist” to Git when adding or removing files. Particularly, a directory will disappear from Git's index when you've deleted all files from it and add that change to the index. Vice-versa, a directory will not be added via git add if it's empty.

Therefore the problem is not about commit history or branches at all: Git will remove the files but will ignore the directories (for which it has no concept). They're not copied, they're simply disregarded where they exist in your directory.

Instead, you might need your own workflow to run [`git clean`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean)—this will permanently delete all untracked directory contents, which are by definition not backed up in git, so read the docs and use extreme caution.

To simply delete empty subdirectories, use [this unix SE answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8430/how-to-remove-all-empty-directories-in-a-subtree) by Christophe Drevet-Droguet:

```
find . -type d -empty -delete
```

Comment: I suggest that you add a warning when proposing to use *git clean* as this is possibly a destructive action which deletes all untracked files without a way to recover them (unless from a backup). Personally, I find your proposition with `find` a very good way to do this.

Comment: @Matt I take your point, but I also deliberately did not include a paste-friendly command because of that risk. Blanket warning to readers: Don't run commands from SO that you don't fully understand. :)

Answer (score 2):

It's not the the directories are being copied between branches, it's just that they aren't being deleted when you switch branches, because Git doesn't have a reason to delete them, yet.

The problem is that your directories are empty. Try creating a file in one of the directories, add it and commit it to one branch. Then switch to the other branch and you'll see that directory disappear.

To avoid this in the future, don't create a directory until you are ready to commit something inside of it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the key line in your `git status` output:

> ```
> No commits yet
> ```

Note how this line repeats even after you run `git commit`.  This is because `git commit` was unable to create a new commit, as there were still no *files* to commit.<sup>1</sup>

As others noted, Git does not store empty directories.  That means these are merely untracked directories (albeit ones with no files in them).  They just stick around between changes of branches.

Once you make some file(s) in some directory, and make commits with those, Git will generally remove the directory once it becomes empty, as you switch from a branch that has some files in that directory to one that does not have any such files.

---

<sup>1</sup>This has a few extra side effects.  In particular, it means you never got `branch-one` created either.  A branch name exists by storing the hash ID of some commit.  With no commits, no branch names can exist at all.  Git nonetheless wants to be "on" some branch, so you're `on branch branch-one` and then later `on branch branch-two`, yet neither branch exists!  So as you switch between nonexistent branches, nothing happens.

You *can* create an initial empty commit using `git commit --allow-empty`.  This allows you to create as many branch names as you like—all selecting this initial empty commit—but there's no real point to that either, and it won't help with the empty directory issue.